# Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n^2}2i=n^4+n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My teacher has given us this problem to do during the weekend but me and my friends could not do by any means:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n^2}2i=n^4+n^2$$

Comment: We too, because it is unclear what you want to say.

Comment: Please give the beginners a chance by refraining from downvoting! :)

Comment: To the poster: What you need hereafter for "properly" asking a question here is not only to post your question but also showing people what you have done or observed.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: Use $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^ki = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$, and substitute $k = n^2$ into the equation.

Answer (score 1):

As Gauss did we he was five years old, prove that:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{m}i = \frac{m(m+1)}{2} $$
(by induction, for instance), then multiply both sides by two and replace $m$ with $n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sum_{1}^{m}i = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ for all integers $m \geq 1.$ Thus
$$\sum_{1}^{n^{2}}2i = 2\sum_{1}^{n^{2}}i = 2\cdot \frac{n^{2}(n^{2}+1)}{2} = n^{4} + n^{2}.$$

To prove the identity applied here note that for $m=1$ we have $\sum_{1}^{m}i = 1 = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}.$ If there is an integer $m \geq 2$ such that $\sum_{1}^{m}i = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$, then we have
$$\sum_{1}^{m+1}i = \sum_{1}^{m}i + (m+1) = \frac{m(m+1)}{2} + (m+1) = \frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2},$$
qed.